# Angular updating component after inserting

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, chatbot

I'm doing a little angular app similar to chat with bots. There a list of "bots chats" and messages in this chats. I created a function which post user message in chat but it shows message only if I refresh the page.

Here's my code:

**bots.service.ts**

```
  getBots() {
    return this.webRequestService.get('');
  }

  getMessages(botsId: string) {
    return this.webRequestService.get(`${botsId}/chats`)
  }

  addMessages(value: string, botsId: string) {
    return this.webRequestService.post(`${botsId}/chats`, {value})
  }
}
```

**chat.component.ts**

```
import {Message} from "../models/message.model";
import {Bots} from "../models/bots.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat-view',
  templateUrl: './chat-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat-view.component.scss']
})
export class ChatViewComponent implements OnInit {

  bots: Bots[];
  messages: Message[];
  botsId: string;

  constructor(private botsService: BotsService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        console.log(params);
        this.botsService.getMessages(params.botsId).subscribe((messages: Message[]) => {
          this.messages = messages;
        })
      }
    )
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        console.log(params);
        this.botsId = params['botsId'];
      }
    )

    this.botsService.getBots().subscribe((bots: Bots[]) => {
      this.bots = bots;
    })

  }
  addNewMessage(value: string){
    this.botsService.addMessages(value, this.botsId).subscribe((newMessage:Message) => {
      console.log(newMessage);
      //this.router.navigate(['./'], {relativeTo: this.route})
    })
  }
}
```

**web-requests.service.ts**

```
 get(uri: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`);
  }
  post(uri: string, payload: Object) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`, payload);
  }
```

The message was successfully added but I don't know how to display it in the chat without updating a page. I've tried to do router on same route but it doesn't works. So i need some advices how to implement it.